# Some ports not showing on nmap

Tags: udp, port, nmap, ntp, netstat

I cannot find my NTP time server port (123)!
I am on Linux Mint Cinnamon

I can find my other ports (22-ssh, 80-http, 3000-rocketchat, and 8000-restaurant-menu) on nmap.
The time port and other ports come up when i run `netstat -anu` but i cannot see the ports listed above. the ports from `netstat` are:

```
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:631             0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 10.0.0.195:36625        0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:49017           0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 10.0.0.195:49175        0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 10.0.0.195:68           10.0.0.1:67             ESTABLISHED
udp        0      0 10.0.0.195:123          0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:123           0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:123             0.0.0.0:*                          
udp6       0      0 2601:18e:8200:43b:33306 :::*                               
udp6       0      0 fe80::53bd:eb08:a46:546 :::*                               
udp6       0      0 :::37553                :::*                               
udp6       0      0 :::50043                :::*                               
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                               
udp6       0      0 2601:18e:8200:43b:39114 :::*                               
udp6       0      0 :::51883                :::*                               
udp6       0      0 :::44314                :::*                               
udp6       0      0 fe80::53bd:eb08:a46:123 :::*                               
udp6       0      0 2601:18e:8200:43b:d:123 :::*                               
udp6       0      0 2601:18e:8200:43b:9:123 :::*                               
udp6       0      0 2601:18e:8200:43b:::123 :::*                               
udp6       0      0 ::1:123                 :::*                               
udp6       0      0 :::123                  :::*
```

Comment: what OS? (`uname` would be good). And have you confirmed your timeserver was running (maybe using `ps -ef`).

Comment: linux. it is running.

Comment: netstat shows only UDP... no TCP listeners at all?

Comment: https://nmap.org/book/scan-methods-udp-scan.html